# MySQL group replication insert statement time sometimes suddenly increases, how is this caused?

Tags: mysql, mysql-innodb-cluster, mysql-group-replication

I used jmeter to stress test the table named test in my innodb cluster. I recorded all sql statements exceeding 1ms in the slow SQL log. I found that the time consumption of insert statements sometimes increased suddenly, but it was irregular.

Comment: Please provide a sample `INSERT`, its time, and the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  These may give us some more tips on where to look next.